# How can a panel appear only when an item is selected from navbar?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, panel, navbar

I have a menu that it looks like in the above code. I want to make visible the Settings panel only when is selected Settings item from Menu navbar. How can I make this possible?

Here is the code:

```
<div class="navbar-menu">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand">Menu</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a>Logout</a></li>
                    <li><a>Settings</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Settings</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li><a>General</a></li> 
            <li><a>Account settings</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's many different ways to do this. One such way is to use *jQuery toggle*.

Working example at **Bootply**:

**http://www.bootply.com/OijQbNdXdk**

Achieved in 4 easy steps:

1. Add id/class to trigger (settings button)

   ```
   <a class="settings-trigger">Settings</a>
   ```
2. Add id/class to your panel to toggle:

   ```
   <div id="settings-panel" class="panel panel-default">
   ```
3. Hide panel intially with CSS:

   ```
   #settings-panel {
     display:none; 
   }
   ```
4. Add jQuery:

   ```
   $( ".settings-trigger" ).click(function() {
     $( "#settings-panel" ).toggle();
   });
   ```

You can get fancier by adding animation, timing, etc. This is a merely a minimal working script.

More on jQuery Toggle:

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/